# Why is portable hotspot and tethering not working?

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

I am trying to use tethering features to connect my laptop to the Internet. On my Samsung Galaxy S3-i9300 device when I enable a portable wi-fi hotspot and connect wirelessly I can connect from my Windows 7 device but not browse the Internet from my laptop.

If instead I use USB-tethering I can browse the Internet from my laptop but sometimes the connection falls and I need to reboot my computer to get the laptop to realize the connection to the Internet is lost. The connection falls for instance when I receive a text message on the phone used for tethering.

Anyone experience these problems and have any solutions?

Comment: What is the Windows 7 device? Is it the PC?

Comment: To be sure, Windows 7 firewall is not blocking access to your hotspot no?

Comment: My issue seems related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245655/my-android-hotspot-is-not-routing-data