# My android hotspot is not routing data

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Currently I am on holidays in France. And strangely my hotspot stopped routing data from connected clients.

Phone: Samsung S20 5G FE
APN: Vodafone
Base country: The Netherlands

My phone's internet connection is running fine. On the phone itself I can easily access any Internet endpoint.

What I have tested:

- Installed an FTP Server on my Android device. Connected perfectly from my laptop to this FTP server. This confirms that my hotspot is really connecting devices to my phone.
- Installed an http proxy on my Android device. Configured the proxy server on my laptop. This works perfectly. Chrome is able to connect with websites through this proxy server running on my phone.

Why is my hotspot not routing data directly? What is blocking this?

I have access to three French operators. None of them seem to make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure your data plan allows tethering with a laptop? Some providers disallow tethering and blocking traffic that comes from a laptop OS. If you can try to tether a second smartphone and check if that works.

Comment: I checked with both ipad as well as another android phone which are both blocking. How can I find out if my data plan disallows tethering? It obviously was always working at home in the Netherlands and it was also working during transit in Belgium and maybe even Luxemburg.

Comment: At the way home as soon as I passed the border of Belgium towards the Netherlands suddenly my hotspot started routing again. I will call Vodafone hopefully to get some explanation.